# Enumerate and change persistent fields in a generic (indirect) manner

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, metadata, hibernate-4.x

In Hibernate 4.x, is there any way to get a list of persistent fields at runtime? By persistent fields I don't mean DB column names, but POJO field names or property names (depending on access type for a particular entity). Also, is there a method to get/set a persistent field's value given a field name as a string, regardless of whether it's a field or property name?

Comment: Generally, you'll get better luck asking for what you want to actually do. It sounds like you have already decided a strategy and are trying to determine a way to do it. Perhaps you should decide on a different strategy? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ColinMorelli: I have an object graph crawler which given a deserialized object received from a client locates a corresponding persistent object and deep-copies the values field-by-field. Before copying each field a check is made whether the current user has sufficient rights to modify the current field, etc. Also, if certain fields of certain entities are modified then a replication with another system or other action is triggered... And all of this is defined externally (i.e. not hardcoded). I'm porting an existing JDO/Datanucleus solution to Hibernate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that everything I need (and more) is contained in `ClassMetadata` class ([documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata.html)).

I can get the metadata for a particular class by using `SessionFactory.getClassMetadata(entityClass)` and then use `metadata.getPropertyNames()`, etc.